# How to export IntelliJ IDEA project as applicaiton

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA version 2017.1.5, and I would like to know how to export my Java project as a runnable application for Windows or Mac.  I am developing on a Windows machine.

What I want is a program that on Windows or Mac, can be installed and then run by clicking an icon, just like you would open Google Chrome, Microsoft Word or any other application.  So far I have only been able to export as an executable .jar file, but when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.Utils.computeTextWidth(Utils.java:118)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.computePrefWidth(LabeledSkinBase.java:734)
        at javafx.scene.control.Control.computePrefWidth(Control.java:537)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.prefWidth(Parent.java:915)
        at javafx.scene.layout.Region.prefWidth(Region.java:1419)
        at javafx.scene.layout.Region.computeChildPrefAreaWidth(Region.java:1728)
        at javafx.scene.layout.GridPane.computePrefWidths(GridPane.java:1556)
        at javafx.scene.layout.GridPane.computePrefWidth(GridPane.java:1242)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.prefWidth(Parent.java:915)
        at javafx.scene.layout.Region.prefWidth(Region.java:1419)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ScrollPaneSkin.computeScrollNodeSize(ScrollPaneSkin.java:929)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ScrollPaneSkin.layoutChildren(ScrollPaneSkin.java:822)
        at javafx.scene.control.Control.layoutChildren(Control.java:578)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1087)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:552)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Scene.java:1646)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_preferredSize(Scene.java:1720)
        at javafx.stage.Window$9.invalidated(Window.java:846)
        at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:109)
        at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
        at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:922)
        at javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:937)
        at javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:259)
        at view.VisualInterface.start(VisualInterface.java:182)
        at model.Generator.start(Generator.java:57)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
        ... 1 more
Exception running application model.Generator
```

I would also like to note that I can't run this .jar file by double-clicking the icon in Windows Explorer, I have to run it from the command line like so:

```
java -jar UPCGen.jar
```

I would like to be able to export to both Mac and Windows.  So either as a runnable .jar, or a .exe (and whatever the file extension is for Mac).  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you using anything in particular (I'm familiar with Maven) to build your application? It looks like the JAR file itself is missing some dependencies.

Comment: As for the actual runnable files, you would have to wrap the JAR file into EXE if you want it to be like a Windows application. I would check out Jar2Exe for stuff like that. As far as Macs go, JREs are no longer installed with the OS, so your install script will have to include its own JRE if you want the JAR to run there.

Comment: Regarding the downvote... why was my post downvoted?  Downvoting without explanation does not give the asker any chance to improve their question or avoid whatever mistake they made in the future.